# Oracle 10: Locally distributed system, problems with UDT

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, ora-00932

I have to set up a distributed object-relational system with replication between two users on the **same database**. That is, I've got a database with **two users** *User1* and *User2*. Both of them use the same script to create the object types and the tables. Some of these tables need have the same content on each user, so I'm using triggers so whenever there's a change on one side, it gets replicated on the other side.

Suppose there's a UDT called **DepartmentType** and another one called **AreaType**. Each Area is related to one Department, and a Department may include many Areas. So, AreaType has a reference to a DepartmentType, and DepartmentType has a nested table of references to AreaTypes. This nested table has a type **NT_AreasInDepartment** (for example). Both types have a primary key called Name. This is the trigger for the insertions on the Department table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NewDept
AFTER INSERT
ON DeptObj
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DIST_DeptObj VALUES (:NEW.Name, :NEW.Areas);
END NewDept;
/
```

It does not work, it says that User1.NT_AreasInDepartment was expected, but User2.NT_AreasInDepartment was found (error ORA-00932). If I use

```
INSERT INTO DIST_DeptObj VALUES (:NEW.Name, :NULL);
```

It works, but I'm not able to insert any record on the nested table afterwards. I've also tried using something like

```
INSERT INTO DIST_DeptObj VALUES (:NEW.Name, NT_AreasInDepartment());
```

But it doesn't work either. In the oracle official forum they told me I could use the same object identifier in to create the types, but given both users are in the same system, that is not possible.

Is there a way of having the same object types used by the two users?

Disclaimer: Probably this looks weird and there may be easier ways of doing this, but I'm afraid this is what I was requested. That is, yes, this is a college assignment. If it were up to me, I wouldn't even be using Oracle.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't have the same type names in each schema. Are any necessary permissions granted to the users so they can see and use each other's types? And can you cast the NEW value when you insert in the trigger, to the other user's type? Failing that you could possibly have a stored procedure in each schema to do the insert, but that might just shift the problem a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does look ugly.
I'd firstly opt for a single UDT that is referenced by both user1 and user2.

Failing that, I'd want some explicit function that breaks the user1.udt down into its components (VARCHAR2, numbers, dates etc.) and uses them in a call to the user2.udt constructor. And vice versa.

An XML based extract/constructor is also worth considering (especially in a production environment if there's a chance that the UDT definitions would get out of step, which they almost certainly would in real life).

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that Oracle enforces strong typing for its user-defined types.  It doesn't matter that `User1.NT_AreasInDepartment` and `User2.NT_AreasInDepartment`  share identical  signatures: they are declared in separate schemas and so are different objects as far as the database is concerned.

> "Is there a way of having the same
>   object types used by the two users?"

Well, the easiest way is to have `NT_AreasInDepartment` owned just by User1 who grants EXECUTE on that it to User2.  However, if you want both schemas to share identical scripts - and that certainly makes it easier to manage replicated environments - then introduce a new schema,  User0, which owns the all objects and grants EXECUTE on them to *both* users.

Comment: I think creating the type only once is the best approach. To make live easier I would simply create a synonym in USER2 pointing to the type in USER1. Therefor the type "looks" identical for bother users